# Get ID of parent DIV

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the ID of the parent div using JavaScript/JQuery.

This is my Razor/HTML:

```
<div id="Container" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;">
    @for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {  
        <div id="abc1_@i" style="height:auto;">
            <div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div>
                        <h3 style="width: 98%; margin-left: 0%;">
                            Section1-@i
                        </h3>
                        <div id="div1" class="ui-state-highlight" 
                            style="width: 98%;">
                        <div id="halfViewList-@i"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
    }
</div>
```

css

```
 #sortable1 {
        border: 1px solid Black;
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 1%;
        width: 48%;
    }
```

And this is how I have been trying to access the ID of the parent div:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("#sortable1,#sortable2").sortable(
    {
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        stop: function (event, ui)
        {
            var drag_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
            alert("drag_id : " + drag_id);
            var parentId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
            var sparent = $("#" + parentId).parent().closest('div').attr("id");
            alert('sparent : ' + sparent);
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

It always returns `abc1_0`. How can I get the ID of the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element should have unique Id.

You are adding one element with same id multiple times which is failing i suspect:

Change following line:

```
<div id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
```

to:

```
<div id="sortable_@(i)" class="connectedSortable mysort">
```

and in jquery:

```
$(".mysort").sortable({
              connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
               stop: function (event, ui) {

               var drag_id = $(ui.item).attr("id");
               alert("drag_id : " + drag_id);

               var parentId = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
               var sparent = $("#" + parentId).parent().closest('div').attr("id");
                    alert('sparent : '+ sparent);
             }
          }).disableSelection();
```

### For CSS:

```
.mysort{
        border: 1px solid Black;
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        margin-left: 1%;
        width: 48%;
    }
```

Comment: how to assign css of sortable1..?

Comment: assign on custom class as i added `mysort`